# Set occurrences in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, find-occurrences

I have a requirement to set the occurrence number of each document type and sort according to document name. Any chance on how to do this in MS SQL 2008?

here are the scenarios:

1. If the document type is unique, update the occurrence number of that document name as 001.
2. if the document type is NOT Unique, check the 6 last digit on the right of the document name and compare it against the other document name with same document type. Please see the current table against the expected output.

Current Table.

```
EE. Number   DocumentType    Document name                 
406453       Transfer        ITransfers 20170531 154323    
406453       Offer Letter    Amendments 20170601 092848            
406453       Offer Letter    Amendments 20170601 092500    
406433       Misc            Misc. 20170531 153348 
406453       Offer Letter    Amendments 20170601 092735
```

Expected Output

```
EE. Number   DocumentType    Document name                 occurrence number
406453       Transfer        ITransfers 20170531 154323    001
406433       Misc            Misc. 20170531 153348         001
406453       Offer Letter    Amendments 20170601 092735    001
406453       Offer Letter    Amendments 20170601 092848    002
406453       Offer Letter    Amendments 20170601 092500    003
```

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by document_type
                          order by right(document_name, 6)
                         ) as occurrence_number
from t;
```

This returns an integer, not a string with leading zeros.  You can convert numbers to strings in any database; the exact functionality depends on the database you are using.

EDIT:

You can convert this to a left-padded string:

```
select t.*,
       right('000' + 
             cast(row_number() over (partition by document_type
                                     order by right(document_name, 6)
                                    ) as varchar(255)
                 ) as occurrence_number
from t;
```

Comment: Hello, It is not the row number. but I need to set the occurrence number based from the document type and document name.

Comment: how do you add 00 on the prefix of row_number()? I tried '00' + row_number() but does not work.